# Error while scanning! java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 19 at 5

Tags: java, maven, spring-data-jpa

We have a project that uses Spring, Java 8, Maven and Hibernate. It builds successfully with

```
mvn clean install -Dskip.unit.tests=true
```

but it errors when we run

```
mvn hibernate:update
```

Comment: Do you think maybe you could [edit] your question and post details of the error that you are getting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does all the dependencies support the version of Java you are using. Look especially close at those manipulating bytecode.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Yes. It support all. Before, it's work fine